# JNI Error In GetStaticMethodID (java_class == null)

Tags: android, java-native-interface, release

Well I'm trying to develop an Android App and i recently added a library from GitHub. When i'm running the app in debug it works fine but when i'm in release the app crashes and i get the next error:

```
A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_class == null
A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to GetStaticMethodID
[...]
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 26017
```

And the code is:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_somepackage_StarterModel_Detector_initiate(JNIEnv *JNI, jclass SelfClass,
                                                                jobject Context) {
if (NULL == State) {
    StateStructure *Blank = (StateStructure *) malloc(sizeof(StateStructure));
    Blank->JNI = JNI;
    Blank->Context = (*JNI)->NewGlobalRef(JNI, Context);
    Blank->AlarmClass = (*JNI)->FindClass(JNI, "com/laifadventure/laifbusiness/StarterModel/Alarm");
    Blank->AlarmClass = (*JNI)->NewGlobalRef(JNI, Blank->AlarmClass);
    Blank->AlarmCall = (*JNI)->GetStaticMethodID(JNI, Blank->AlarmClass, "call",
                                                 "(Landroid/content/Context;)V");
    InitiateBuffer(Blank);
    InitiateSamples(Blank);
    InitiateResampling(Blank);
    InitiateFiltering(Blank);
    InitiateDeltas(Blank);
    InitiateSV(Blank);
    InitiateEvents(Blank);
    InitiateProtection(Blank);
    InitiateSensor(Blank);
    State = Blank;
}
}
```

Why does it happens in release only and how can it be solved?

**SOLUTION**

I finally managed to find my problem. In my gradle file i enabled the parameter "minifyEnabled" to true in the release configuration.
By just disable to false this parameter my app started to work as expected.

Comment: You should use the **ndk-stack** tool in Android **NDK** to find out the  *position* where it is crashing. see the link about [ndk stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html).

Comment: You've caused this mystery yourself. There is a distressing lack of error checking in your code. *Every* JNI call must be error-checked, and a suitable exception thrown or error logged. Clearly in this case the class wasn't found, presumably missing from your release.

Comment: It seems your C++ library is calling a Java method that does not exist in the release. So your **gradle** for **release** must be *faulty* (**proguard** for example).

Comment: What others said. Also the error message says the class is null. So the real question is: why doesn't it find the class

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i finally managed to find the problem. In my gradle configuration I enabled the "minifyEnabled" parameter to true.
I changed it to false and it works as expected

Comment: `minifyEnabled` may still be desirable (that's really up to you). So instead of turning it off altogether you might want to consider adding some proguard rules to exclude certain classes/members from removal/renaming.